# AOP Logging: @Aspect is not logging the error in console for log4j default configuration

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-aop

I'm new to Spring and trying to implement Spring AOP using log4j to log errors in console.
Please note that I don't have log4j.xml in my project but that should be fine as I just want to log the error in the console using Spring AOP concept.

Below is my code and when I run this, I can see the Exception stack trace in the console but I don't see my LoggingAspect.java is logging the error in the console as it should be.

I've tried adding a static block in LoggingAspect.java to print some text in the console using System.out.println(), but it's not printing.

SpringConfig.java

```
package exercise5.com.aadi.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "exercise5.com.aadi.service")
public class SpringConfig {
}
```

LoggingAspect.java

```
package exercise5.com.aadi.utility;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* exercise5.com.aadi.service.*Impl.*(..))", throwing = "exception")
    public void logExceptionFromService(Exception exception) throws Exception {
        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());
        logger.error(exception);
    }
}
```

My Exception is coming from DAO

InsuranceServiceImpl.java

```
package exercise5.com.aadi.service;

...
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

...

@Service(value = "insuranceService")
public class InsuranceServiceImpl implements InsuranceService {

    ...

    @Override
    public List<PolicyReport> getReport(String policyType) throws Exception {
        ...

        if (filteredPolicy.isEmpty())
            throw new Exception("Service.NO_RECORD");

        ...

    }

    ...
}
```

Below is the console message I'm getting

```
ERROR StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration (logging only errors to the console), or user programmatically provided configurations. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j 2 internal initialization logging. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for instructions on how to configure Log4j 2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Service.NO_RECORD
    at exercise5.com.aadi.service.InsuranceServiceImpl.getReport(InsuranceServiceImpl.java:43)
    at exercise5.com.aadi.ui.UserInterface.generateReport(UserInterface.java:45)
    at exercise5.com.aadi.ui.UserInterface.main(UserInterface.java:20)
```

But what I'm expecting is

```
ERROR StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration (logging only errors to the console), or user programmatically provided configurations. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j 2 internal initialization logging. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for instructions on how to configure Log4j 2
Exception in thread "main" 02:03:52.656 [main] ERROR exercise5.com.aadi.service.InsuranceServiceImpl
java.lang.Exception: Service.NO_RECORD
    at exercise5.com.aadi.service.InsuranceServiceImpl.getReport(InsuranceServiceImpl.java:56) [bin/:?]
    at exercise5.com.aadi.ui.UserInterface.generateReport(UserInterface.java:45) [bin/:?]
    at exercise5.com.aadi.ui.UserInterface.main(UserInterface.java:20) [bin/:?]
java.lang.Exception: Service.NO_RECORD
    at exercise5.com.aadi.service.InsuranceServiceImpl.getReport(InsuranceServiceImpl.java:56)
    at exercise5.com.aadi.ui.UserInterface.generateReport(UserInterface.java:45)
    at exercise5.com.aadi.ui.UserInterface.main(UserInterface.java:20)
```

Note that two times the Exception Log should be there. First one from Spring AOP LoggingAspect.java and the second one is the normal Exception stack trace.

Anyone can help me out, why I'm not getting the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're specifying

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "exercise5.com.aadi.service")
```

Which means your `LoggingAspect` `@Component` won't be picked up by Spring, because it lives under

```
exercise5.com.aadi.utility
```

Other than that your AOP configuration seems on point.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It fixed the issue when I added the LoggingAspect class' package under basePackages of SpringConfig class.

Comment: Though I'm having another issue. `ctx.getBean(InsuranceServiceImpl.class)` is giving me NoSuchBeanDefinitionException. whereas `ctx.getBean("insuranceService")` is working absolutely fine. Any clue?

Comment: @Aadi InsuranceServiceImpl seems like a concrete implementation, Maybe you need to ask for the relative base interface.

Comment: Wow! can't believe. It fixed when I add `ctx.getBean(InsuranceService.class)`. You are a genius. Thanks a lot. But I don't get the reason why InsuranceServiceImpl.class did not work? In which scenario do I need to do like getBean(...Service.class)? or getBean(....ServiceImpl.class) is always wrong?

Comment: @Aadi It depends. The question you need to ask yourself is, does this class implement an interface? If it does, usually the right one to ask for is the interface. If it doesn't, you're forced to go with the concrete class.

Comment: @Aadi it's nothing.